# psychokinetic, is this the right word

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm pretty sure I've got this one all wrong. I'm trying to find a word combination that explains when somebody telepathically pokes around inside your head with ill intent.

> “WHAT? Are you saying she *psychokineticly* attacked you?” Domá asked.
> “that's what I've been trying to tell you, they lived through an
> attack like that. They this may be the first mortal to survive,” said
> Lugaid.
> “Is that what you call it when she creeps around in your head,
> *psychokinetic*?” Seamus asked.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Psychokenetic" would be when he moves something using only his mind.  (kinetic = relating to motion) What is wrong with "telepathic" for your purposes?

Comment: Rowling coined the term 'legilimency' for mind-reading and in some cases mind-manipulation. But unlike 'quidditch' and 'muggle', it doesn't appear to have made it into a major dictionary, and should thus probably be regarded as being outside the lexicon.

Comment: *Are you saying she attacked you psychically?* As for a noun or adjective, I think you'll have to coin one. Too bad [*psycholepsy*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22psycholepsy%22) / *psycholeptic* (mind [attack](https://wordinfo.info/unit/1172)) are taken.

Comment: @TinfoilHat, psycholepsy is a great play on words. maybe a combination of Psycho and attack. and Yeah the attack feels physical to its victoms. Like psychoblitz or psyco-onslaught

Comment: No "attack" here, but [metapsychosis](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/metapsychosis)... Also _psych**e**lepsis_ is all yours.

Comment: There is the quote "I'm not putting up with your macho head games anymore." from Seinfeld.